# Разработка плагина

Tags: wordpress

Разработал плагин и отправил его на публикацию, его утвердили и дали мне доступ к SVN. В целом всё нормально, НО не могу нигде найти ответы на такие вопросы:

1. Есть файл readme.txt, который на английском языке, как его можно перевести на другие языки?
2. В папке assest хранятся банеры, скриншоты, логотипы и тд. Можно ли их сделать для каждого языка свои?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как зальёте в репозиторий, появится возможность перевести readme на translate.wordpress.org. [Пример](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/ru/default/wp-plugins/dco-insert-analytics-code).
2. Насколько я знаю — нет, но можно, например, сделать документацию на своём сайте для разных языков и соответствующие ссылки проставить при переводе.